# Is Polymer to succeed Web UI

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-polymer, polymer

Could someone please explain something for me.

I am confused. Currently Polymer and Web UI seems to be two separate projects with a lot of similarities.

Is Polymer to succeed Web UI - meaning Web UI will be discontinued in favour of Polymer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Polymer is the successor to Web UI. At some point in the future, once Polymer is more stable, Web UI will be abandoned.

For now though, it still may make sense to use Web UI if you need it for a production app.

Comment: Thanks. I am no longer confused.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, yes Polymer is the next version of web_ui. It is being developed in conjunction with the JavaScript version of Polymer. web_ui is currently in extended support mode, in which bug fixes are applied to keep the library functional (particularly as new SDK releases are made), however there will be no new functionality added to web_ui.

As of yesterday, the integrated build reached 0.8.1, and with Polymer 0.8.1, Polymer has virtually reached parity with web_ui and in some areas already surpassed with additional functionality.

Google has committed to maintaining web_ui for existing projects, however I would highly recommend that any new projects be started with Polymer. It is also the time to look at porting any old web_ui projects over to the new libraries (something I'm in the process of doing myself).

Comment: Thanks. I am no longer confused.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about moving to Polymer is that the size of compiled JS is still quite large. Really, until [Issue 12396](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12396) is fixed, I can't see myself using Polymer for any decently sized production app.